# How can I use "git describe --match" sensibly in combination with a shallow clone?

Tags: git

I am using `git describe` as the driver for versioning in my application at build time.
It looks roughly like: `git describe  --always --dirty --match version*`

I tag my versions with a pattern like `version.1.2.3` and the build figures out the version of the application based off what the last commit that was tagged with something like `version.*` was.
If I haven't tagged a given commit, then the version number ends up something like `version.1.14.3-24-ged66bf5`, which is based of the most recent tag, how many commits since that tag and the git commit id.

This works really well for me personally, but I'm having a problem with doing builds off of a shallow clone on my CI server.

When using the "shallow clone" option on my git build in jenkins (I'm guessing it's just doing "--depth=1"), my `git describe` command is no longer doing what I want it to do.
My version number just ends up being the commit id - I guess this is because there are no tagged versions in the shallow clone, so the `--always` parameter for the describe command just ends up spitting out the commit id.

I can deal with this for the moment by not doing a shallow clone.

But I really like driving my versioning off of the git describe - how can I keep using it even with shallow clones?
I think what I need to be able to do is specify at the time of the shallow clone, that I want the depth to be "from the tip of the branch back to the latest version that has a tag matching `version.*`".

Is that a thing I can do with Git?

Comment: Have you thought of creating a `git alias` that does just that? I'm by no means an expert on creating sophisticated ones, but I know that you can get pretty crazy workflows implemented, by using them.

Alternatively use git hooks that listen to your deployment branch (`post-commit-hook`) and do pretty much the same thing.

Comment: @JensHöpken What would this git alias look like?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't: a shallow clone is missing the tag objects and commits they tag.

More precisely, this depends on the *depth* of that clone and how far back one must go in history to find appropriate tags.  Making your shallow clone with `--depth 1000` might suffice, for instance.  The precise number depends on how many commits you have between<sup>1</sup> the tags you care about.

You are correct that if git provided a "deepen until tagged", that would do the trick, but git doesn't, and worse, deepening a shallow clone does not automatically bring over tags.

(It would be possible to write a script that uses `git ls-remote` and `git fetch --depth` to keep deepening a clone until some tagged commit(s) appear, then have the script apply the tags manually, as it were.  This probably would only take a few dozen lines of Python or shell code, for instance, depending on how robust you wanted it.  But it's not included with git itself.)

---

<sup>1</sup>The notion of "between" is a bit iffy in a non-linear graph, but the general idea should be clear enough here, I think.