Using `git describe` on github or gitlab?
I use git describe as a means to obtain a sensible version number for software I build & install from a non-release checkout of a git repository.
Is there a way to get the output of that command directly (for the given/current commit) via the github or gitlab web interfaces, rather than having to clone the repository locally, checkout the desired commit and then running the command?
Example: I've identified the last WebKit commit that supports using GLX with the GTk port (#ec3dd91419a8c035ddb2c79bbd85a93619bab1e9). I plan to fetch the tarball to build from that but this won't give me the proper version number. I don't know of a way to clone and check out a repo at a specific commit so I'm now waiting for a clone starting (tentatively!) at jan 1st 2022 until today which is an almost complete waste of my time and bandwidth ...

I guess you should use https://docs.github.com/en/actions

"I don't know of a way to clone and check out a repo at a specific commit" - does this not work? git clone <url>; cd <repo dir>; git checkout <commit hash>

@mkrieger1 AFAIU the OP wants to say, that the history started at the Jan 1st 2022 but with git clone he doesn't need to clone the entire history because for git describe he only needs may be a dozen of commits. So the question is: how to clone as little as possible (but longer than just --depth=1) and still allow to run git describe properly?

Search gave me these results: https://github.com/proudust/gh-describe , https://stackoverflow.com/a/36389573/7976758


how can cloning a repository start in the past? Using the counter-intuitively named --shallow-since argument, which starts the cloning process at the indicated YYYY-MM-DD date (it's really --starting-at or --shallow-before). GH shows me the date of the commit I'm interested in so cloning just that date range would be an option, but still a waste of bandwidth if I could get the output of git describe <commit> from the GH interface without any cloning at all. (I think the .git directory I cloned was about 3Gb small...)

